# ColdFusion Services are not present in Services dialog

Tags: coldfusion, windows-10, coldfusion-10

I installed ColdFusion 10 on Windows 10 and the mandatory update with the HotFix no 18 (for Windows 10). After restarting the Windows server the services are not present and I got the following error:

```
Error loading: D:\\ColdFusion10\\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Comment: Does the user that the ColdFusion service is running as have permissions to that folder/file?

Comment: yes it has permission

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch Command prompt as Administrator.

For the main application server service, run this command:

`sc create "ColdFusion 10 Application Server" binPath= C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\coldfusionsvc.exe start= auto DisplayName= "ColdFusion 10 Application Server"`

This can be applied to all the other services as well, I will enumerate a few:

- ColdFusion 10 .NET Service (C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jnbridge\CFDotNetsvc.exe)
- ColdFusion 10 Jetty Service (C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jetty\jetty.exe -zglaxservice ColdFusion10JettyService)
- ColdFusion 10 ODBC Agent (C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\db\slserver54\bin\swagent.exe "ColdFusion 10 ODBC Agent")
- ColdFusion 10 ODBC Server (C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\db\slserver54\bin\swstrtr.exe "ColdFusion 10 ODBC Server")

For CF11, the paths inside the CF installation are the same. There is one additional service, ColdFusion 11 Add-on Services (C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\jetty\jetty.exe -zglaxservice ColdFusion11Add-onServices), instead of the Jetty Service that CF10 has.